# Why some functions ends with an ! (an exclamation point) in Julia?

Tags: julia

Some function(s) in Julia ends with an exclamation point e.g. `pop!`, `sort!` etc.

Answer (score 5):

By convention, function names ending with an exclamation point (`!`) modify their arguments. Some functions have both modifying (e.g., `sort!`) and non-modifying (`sort`) versions.

[more can be found here:](http://mortenpi.eu/gsoc2019-mockups/bulma/v4/julia/base/base.html)